# Sync a directory between two shared hosting servers using rsync

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, rsync, synchronization

I have two shared hosting servers and I need to sync a directory with subfiles/directories using `rsync` via SSH automatically.

Mean: If server1 had changed server2 updates the changes. If server2 had changed server1 updates the changes.

I can use cron but I don't know the best way to do that.

Comment: You're describing shared fs, for instance NFS. You cannot achieve that with rsync since rsync uses the changes vector, *source -> destination*, and in your case there's no constant direction. Bet that question will be voted down and closed.

Comment: @drookie As I understood from you, with `rsync` there is only `Master` -> `Slave`, I cant use `Master`<->`Master` right? If your answer is yes, Can you tell me the ways to do it?

Comment: `unison` allows to do `Master <-> Master` synchronization.